# Communicating between MEF objects

Tags: mvvm, mef, mvvm-light

I'm building a workbench/IDE style application which uses MEF to locate and load tools into the workbench at start up.

I'm using MVVM Light to build the workbench and the separate tools. I've got a point now where I want tools to be able to communicate which each other and the workbench.

I don't mean direct communication, more like "Hey I have some data here if anyone's interested" and interested tools can pick up the data.

This looks much like C# events and I know I can export an interface from my tool(s) which defines the event(s) but I'm also wondering about using the MVVM Light messenger to provide the communication.

I've seen on here that people are using the EventAggregator from Prism to do the same thing and as the messenger from MVVM Light is roughly analogous I figured I could use it.

I'm after advice really, has anyone used the messenger for MEF - MEF object and would you advocate it over plain old C# events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at here is the mediator pattern.  You could use plain old C# events to do the same thing... but do to it right you would most likely end up implementing your own kind of pub/sub pattern.  And if you are going to do that, why re-invent the wheel?

I like using prism's EventAggregator because it is part of the Prism framework injected with MEF.  I use a lot of other things from Prism, so it's nice to get this for 'free'. It also promotes loose coupling with your components, and like all of the good mediator implementations it is implemented with the weak event pattern which prevents the memory issues you would need to avoid yourself when destroying objects that have subscribed to an event.

For what it's worth, I used to use MVVM Light, but I found Prism to be a more mature framework, with better documentation, examples and a larger user base to learn from.  That's really just my opinion- I know loads of people who love MVVM Light.  Play with them both and pick the one that makes you happy :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nicros, I ended up using the messenger from MVVM Light. I will look at Prism at a later date but I've got a technology/proof of concept to deliver ATM so I'm a bit pushed for time, cheers